How to better animate a curve modifier without moving the object itself?
I'm rolling up a scroll by applying a curve modifier to the "scroll" mesh with a spiral curve. The animation itself is made by parenting both scroll and spiral to an empty, moving the location of the scroll, while also animating the location of the parent empty.
This works fine, but lining up the animation curves to make the edge of the paper look like it isn't moving is tedious and time consuming, and it isn't even perfect. And if I want to add a little bounce to the end of the unfurling, this problem is compounded. I'm assuming I'm missing something fundamental here.
Ideally I'd like to just constrain the scroll and only move the spiral somehow, but am unsure where to start, any direction or other ways to approach this would be appreciated!
Also, I posted a screen record of the project here: https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/1fsahjl/comment/lpixles/?context=3

Hello, it's a good idea to parent both the paper and curve to an empty and move the empty, i'm not sure why you say that "lining up the animation curves to make the edge of the paper look like it isn't moving is tedious and time consuming", it took me only 3 mn to do the whole animation, could you please share your file?
